# I don't know how to check if two values already exists in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse

I'm programming in Eclipse java and want to see if the two values ​​for the variable 'gebruikersnaam' and 'geboortejaar' exist in my sql workbench database.

this is my sql statement:

```
INSERT_SPELER="INSERT INTO ID372579_SDPG24.Speler(gebruikersnaam,geboortejaar,speelkansen)"+"VALUES(?,?,?) ";
```

Can you add something to tge statement that helps?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Workbench database` the database is MySQL and workbench is just a tool written to make accessing a MySQL database more friendly

Comment: Its not your problem, but why split the query into 2 sepecrate strings?

Comment: Try and select it, if you cannot they dont exists!

Comment: @riggs Yes, MySQL is whitespace sensitive in certain cases.

Comment: *want to see if the two values ​​for the variable 'gebruikersnaam' and 'geboortejaar' exist* Create unique index. If this values pair exists already then the insertion will fail.